# Escaping part of a regular expression in MongoDB C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I am using MongoDB 3.4 with the C++ driver (latest version, 3.1.1). I need to query for an item via `$regex` that starts with the given `prefix`. Currently, I use the following query document:

```
auto query = bsoncxx::builder::stream::document()
        << "item" << bsoncxx::types::b_regex("^" + prefix, "")
    << bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
```

However, this fails to work when `prefix` contains special characters, like `$`. Is there a way of escaping `prefix` or rewriting the document creation above so that it works regardless of the used characters in `prefix`?